# Getting "Path not found: POST /" error when submitting contact form hosted on DataFire

Tags: contacts, contact-form

I have a static site that uses a contact form that is hosted on a fork of this repo: https://app.datafire.io/projects?baseRepo=https:%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FDataFire-repos%2Fcontact-us-base

Everything seems to be in order and it works successfully and delivers emails when I test it on Datafire, but when deployed on my site, sumbitting the form gives me the error "Path not found: POST /", so I'm not sure why I get this routing error when I try to submit it from my site.

This is the form action:

```
<form action="https://sub-tm.prod.with-datafire.io" method="post">
```

and as I said, it works when tested from DataFire.

edit: I just noticed the log on datafire shows this:

```
WARNING! Unable to find a Swagger path that matches "/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your action is on the `/contact` endpoint. So it should work if you change the URL to `https://sub-tm.prod.with-datafire.io/contact`

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much!